# C# Convert BINARY to TEXT and then search it

Tags: c#

I would like to search for a text in binary file.

Let's say I would like to find a word `SEQUENCE`.

I have tried with binary reader but didn't have luck. I can't pull text from binary file.

My current code looks like this:

```
txtSource.Text = string.Empty;
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

try
{
   if (result == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      txtFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

      string s;

      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(txtFile.Text, FileMode.Open))
      using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
      {
          byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
          txtSource.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(bin);
      }
```

Regards,

Igor

Comment: Aren't all files binary at some level?

Answer (score 4):

Trying to read strings out of binary data is an approach that will cause problems (as not all binary data can be converted into a meaningful text form). It's better to work out what the binary sequence of bytes will be used to represent the text, and search the binary of the file for that binary data.

Strings can be stored in many different forms. Assuming the strings are stored raw (uncompressed and unencrypted), then you just need to know the encoding used (are they 8-bit ASCII characters or 16-bit UNICODE ones, for example?)

If you know the encoding, you can convert a C# string into a binary representation using one of the many overrides of [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx) in .net. For example, if you want to look for the ASCII string "SEQUENCE", then the byte-sequence you're looking for can be generated using

```
byte[] binary = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SEQUENCE");
```

You can then search for this binary in the file. A simple brute-force approach is to read bytes from the file (i.e. `Stream.ReadByte`) and compare them to this 'binary' byte array to see if a match can be found. (There are some clever algorithms you can use to do this more quickly and efficiently by minimising the number of bytes you need to read and compare, and buffering/caching strategies can significantly improve performance of the I/O involved, but I suggest you get something working before you worry about performance improvements)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ASCII.GetString()** function from the **System.Text** namespace to read string from a byte array.

Comment: Or UTF8.GetString(). Or Unicode.GetString(). Or UTF32.GetString(). Or UTF7.GetString(). He hasn't mentioned his encoidng.

Comment: I only get first word from file. Text after NUL... is not shown.